# PHP and MSSQL DB

Tags: php, sql-server

Can anyone help me out, please. I am looking on how to connect to MS SQL from PHP form and than submit data from that form to SQL db.

My main question is how to connect/make PHP communicate to MS SQL?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-query.php

There are examples how you can connect

Answer (score 1):

the manual knows all: http://nz.php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php